# OpenCL result changes depending on result of printf? What?

Tags: vector, opencl

OpenCL kernel crunches some numbers. This particular kernel then searches an array of 8 bit char4 vectors for a matching string of numbers. For example, array holds 3 67 8 2 56 1 3 7 8 2 0 2 - the kernel loops over that (actual string is 1024 digits long) and searches for 1 3 7 8 2 and "returns" data letting the host program know it found a match.

In an combo learning exercise/programming experiment I wanted to see if I could loop over an array and search for a range of values, where the array is not just char values, but char4 vectors, WITHOUT using a single if statement in the kernel. Two reasons:

1: After half an hour of getting compile errors I realized that you cannot do:

```
if(charvector[3] == searchvector[0])
```

Because some may match and some may not. And 2:

I'm new to OpenCL and I've read a lot about how branches can hurt a kernel's speed, and if I understand the internals of kernels correctly, some math may actually be faster than if statements. Is that the case?

Anyway... first, the kernel in question:

```
void search(__global uchar4 *rollsrc, __global uchar *srch, char srchlen)
{
  size_t gx = get_global_id(0);
  size_t wx = get_local_id(0);
  __private uint base = 0;
  __local uchar4 queue[8092];
  __private uint chunk = 8092 / get_local_size(0);
  __private uint ctr, start, overlap = srchlen-1;
  __private int4 srchpos = 0, srchtest = 0;
  uchar4 searchfor;
  event_t e;

  start = max((int)((get_group_id(0)*32768) - overlap), 0);

  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
  e = async_work_group_copy(queue, rollsrc+start, 8092, 0);
  wait_group_events(1, &e);

  for(ctr = 0; ctr < chunk+overlap; ctr++) {
    base = min((uint)((get_group_id(0) * chunk) + ctr), (uint)((N*32768)-1));
    searchfor.x = srch[max(srchpos.x, 0)]; 
    searchfor.y = srch[max(srchpos.y, 0)]; 
    searchfor.z = srch[max(srchpos.z, 0)]; 
    searchfor.w = srch[max(srchpos.w, 0)]; 
    srchpos += max((convert_int4(abs_diff(queue[base], searchfor))*-100), -100) | 1;
    srchpos = max(srchpos, 0);
    srchtest = clamp(srchpos-(srchlen-1), 0, 1) << 31;
    srch[0] |= (any(srchtest) * 255); 

//  if(get_group_id(0) == 0 && get_local_id(0) == 0) 
//    printf("%u: %v4u   %v4u\n", ctr, srchpos, srchtest);
  }
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
}
```

There's extra unneeded code in there, this was a copy from a previous kernel, and I havent cleaned up the extra junk yet. That being said.. in short and in english, how the math based if statement works:

Since I need to search for a range, and I'm searching a vector, I first set a char4 vector (searchfor) to have elements xyzw individually set to the number I am searching for. It's done individually because each of xyz and w hold a different stream, and the search counter - how many matches in a row we've had - will be different for each of the members of the vector. I'm sure there's a better way to do it than what I did. Suggestions?

So then, an int4 vector, searchpos, which holds the current position in the search array for each of the 4 vector positions, gets this added to it:

```
max((convert_int4(abs_diff(queue[base], searchfor))*-100), -100) | 1;
```

What this does: Take the ABS difference between the current location in the target queue (queue) and the searchfor vector set in the previous 4 lines. A vector is returned where each member will have either a positive number (not a match) or zero (a match - no difference).

It's converted to int4 (as uchar cannot be negative) then multipled by -100, then run through max(x,-100). Now the vector is either -100, or 0. We OR it with 1 and now it's -99 or 1.

End result: searchpos either increments by 1 (a match), or is reduced by 99, resetting any previous partial match increments. (Searches can be up to 96 characters long - there exists a chance to match 91, then miss, so it has to be able to wipe that all out). It is then max'ed with 0 so any negative result is clamped to zero. Again - open to suggestions to make that more efficient. I realized as I was writing this I could probably use addition with saturation to remove some of the max statements.

The last part takes the current srchpos, which now equals the number of consecutive matches, subtracts 1 less than the length of the search string, then clamps it to 0-1, thus ending up with either a 1 - a full match, or 0. We bit shift this << 31. Result is 0, or 0x8000000. Put this into srchtest.

Lastly, we bitwise OR the first character of the search string with the result of any(srchtest) * 255 - it's one of the few ways (I'm aware of) to test something across a vector and return a single integer from it. (any() returns 1 if any member of the vector has it's MSB set - which we set in the line above)

End result? srch[0] is unchanged, or, in the case of a match, it's set to 0xff. When the kernel returns, the host can read back srch from the buffer. If the first character is 0xff, we found a match.

It probably has too many steps and can be cleaned up. It also may be less efficient than just doing 4 if checks per loop. Not sure.

But, after this massive post, the thing that has me pulling my hair out:

When I UNCOMMENT the two lines at the end that prints debug information, the script works. This is the end of the output on my terminal window as I run it:

```
36: 0,0,0,0   0,0,0,0
37: 0,0,0,0   0,0,0,0
38: 0,0,0,0   0,0,0,0
39: 0,0,0,0   0,0,0,0

Search = 613.384 ms
Positive
Done read loop: -1 27 41
```

Positive means the string was found. The -1 27 41 is the first 3 characters of the search string, the first being set to -1 (signed char on the host side).

Here's what happens when I comment out the printf debugging info:

```
Search = 0.150 ms
Negative
Done read loop: 55 27 41
```

IT DOES NOT FIND IT. What?! How is that possible? Of course, I notice that the script execution time jumps from .15ms to 600+ms because of the printf, so I think, maybe it's somehow returning and reading the data BEFORE the script ends, and the extra delay from the printf gives it a pause. So I add a barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE); to the end, thinking that will make sure all threads are done before returning. Nope. No effect. I then add in a 2 second sleep on the host side, after running the kernel, after running clFinish, and before running clReadBuffer.

NOPE! Still Negative. But I put the printf back in - and it works. How is that possible? Why? Does anyone have any idea? This is the first time I've had a programming bug that baffled me to the point of pulling hair out, because it makes absolutely zero sense. The work items are not clashing, they each read their own block, and even have an overlap in case the search string is split across two work item blocks.

Please - save my hair - how can a printf of irrelevant data cause this to work and removing it causes it to not?

Oh - one last fun thing: If I remove the parameters from the printf - just have it print text like "grr please work" - the kernel returns a negative, AND, nothing prints out. The printf is ignored.

What the heck is going on? Thanks for reading, I know this was absurdly long.

Comment: Can you provide the full kernel code, and describe how you are launching it (global and local sizes, argument values)?

Comment: That is the full kernel code. Unless you mean the other unrelated kernels? Global size is 32768, local is 64. `EC("Ksearch", clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel_search, 1, NULL, &conv_size, &conv_work, 0, NULL, &event));` is the launch line. conv_size and conv_work are integers of 32768 and 64. Arguments to the kernel are buffers. EC is a macro that checks and halts/reports on errors.

Comment: To be sure, I just added a new uint global buffer, 4 bytes, set it to 0, passed it to the kernel as global uint *retval, and I set retval to 255 in the case of a match. Without the printf, it reads 0 after the kernel finishes. With the printf, it reads 255. I wanted to eliminate the hack of using the search term as the return value. Still does not work.

Comment: OK, and what is the value of the `N` macro/constant used inside the kernel?

Comment: Wow, you asking that totally made me see the problem. This is the 5th kernel in a series that works on this data. All other kernels have each work item take one 'thread' of numbers and work. This one, being last, just reads the entire result array as one long stream so it works differently. Unfortunately 32768 work items * 8092 (a typo, should have been 8192) is WAY out of bounds for the array sized at 32768*1024. Since I was copying prior kernels and they all worked on the same data, but different, it didnt occur to me that work size/groups would be too large for the input data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone referencing this question in the future, the issue was caused by my arrays being read out of bounds. When that happens, all heck breaks loose and all results are unpredictable.

Once I fixed the work and group size and made sure I was not exceeding the memory bounds, it worked as expected.